How to Pre-Bind Parameters in a Template-Based Event System in C++
I have an event system in my game engine, consisting of two main components: Event and EventCallback.
Event.h:
#ifndef _EVENT_H_
#define _EVENT_H_
#include "EventCallback.h"
#include <vector>

template<typename... Args>
class Event
{
public:
    Event() = default;
    ~Event()
    {
        for (IEventCallback<Args...>* action : m_actions)
            delete action;

        m_actions.clear();
    }

    void AddListener(IEventCallback<Args...>* action)
    {
        m_actions.push_back(action);
    }

    void RemoveListener(IEventCallback<Args...>* action)
    {
        auto position = std::find(m_actions.begin(), m_actions.end(), action);

        if (position == m_actions.end())
            return;

        m_actions.erase(position);

        if(action != nullptr)
            delete action;
    }

    void Trigger(Args... args)
    {
        for (IEventCallback<Args...>* action : m_actions)
        {
            action->Trigger(args...);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<IEventCallback<Args...>*> m_actions;
};

#endif


EventCallback.h:
#ifndef _EVENTCALLBACK_H_
#define _EVENTCALLBACK_H_

template<typename... Args>
class IEventCallback
{
public:
    virtual bool operator == (IEventCallback* other) = 0;
    virtual void Trigger(Args... args) = 0;
};
 
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class EventCallback : public IEventCallback<Args...>
{    
public:    
    EventCallback(T* instance, void (T::* function)(Args... args))
    {
        m_instance = instance;
        m_function = function;
    }
    virtual void Trigger(Args... args) override
    { 
        if(m_instance != nullptr)
            (m_instance->*m_function)(args...);
    } 
    
    virtual bool operator == (IEventCallback<Args...>* other) override
    {
        EventCallback<T, Args...>* otherEventCallback = dynamic_cast<EventCallback<T, Args...>*>(other);
        if (otherEventCallback == nullptr)
            return false;

        return  (this->m_function == otherEventCallback->m_function) &&
                (this->m_instance == otherEventCallback->m_instance);
    }

private:
    void (T::*m_function)(Args...);
    T* m_instance;
};

#endif


Currently, I can create an event and add listeners like this:
CameraController* instance = new CameraController();
Event<InputCallbackData> Ongoing;
Ongoing.AddListener(new EventCallback<CameraController, InputCallbackData>(this, &CameraController::MoveRight));

void CameraController::MoveRight(InputCallbackData data)
{
    Vector3D cameraPos = m_cameraComponent->GetWorldPosition();
    Vector3D cameraRight = m_cameraComponent->GetWorldRotation().GetRightDirection();

    m_cameraComponent->SetWorldPosition(cameraPos + cameraRight * movementSpeed);
}

InputCallbackData inputCallbackData = InputCallbackData();
Ongoing.Trigger(inputCallbackData);


Now, I would like to pre-bind parameters to the EventCallback. Here is what I am aiming for:
CameraController* instance = new CameraController();
Event<InputCallbackData> Ongoing;
Ongoing.AddListener(new EventCallback<CameraController, InputCallbackData>(this, &CameraController::MoveRight, 10));

void CameraController::MoveRight(InputCallbackData data, float speed)
{
    Vector3D cameraPos = m_cameraComponent->GetWorldPosition();
    Vector3D cameraRight = m_cameraComponent->GetWorldRotation().GetRightDirection();

    m_cameraComponent->SetWorldPosition(cameraPos + cameraRight * speed);
}

InputCallbackData inputCallbackData = InputCallbackData();
Ongoing.Trigger(inputCallbackData);


How should I modify my EventCallback class to support pre-binding parameters?
I don't know how to process to achive my goal :
CameraController* instance = new CameraController();
Event<InputCallbackData> Ongoing;
Ongoing.AddListener(new EventCallback<CameraController, InputCallbackData>(this, &CameraController::MoveRight, 10));

void CameraController::MoveRight(InputCallbackData data, float speed)
{
    Vector3D cameraPos = m_cameraComponent->GetWorldPosition();
    Vector3D cameraRight = m_cameraComponent->GetWorldRotation().GetRightDirection();

    m_cameraComponent->SetWorldPosition(cameraPos + cameraRight * speed);
}

InputCallbackData inputCallbackData = InputCallbackData();
Ongoing.Trigger(inputCallbackData);

Edit (Finded solution) :
#ifndef _EVENTCALLBACK_H_
#define _EVENTCALLBACK_H_
#include <functional>

template<typename... Args>
class ICallback
{
public:
    virtual void Call(Args... args) = 0;
};


template<typename... Args>
class IEventCallback
{
public:
    virtual bool operator == (IEventCallback* other) = 0;
    virtual void Trigger(Args... args) = 0;
};
 
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class EventCallback : public IEventCallback<Args...>
{    
public:    
    template <typename... ExtraArgs>
    EventCallback(T* instance, void (T::*function)(Args..., ExtraArgs...), const ExtraArgs&... extra_args)
    {
        class MethodWrapper : public ICallback<Args...> 
        {
        public:
            MethodWrapper(T* instance, void (T::* function)(Args..., ExtraArgs...), const ExtraArgs&... extra_args)
                : m_instance(instance), m_function(function), m_extra_args(std::make_tuple(extra_args...))
            {}

            virtual void Call(Args... args) override
            {
                //Expand a tuple into variadic template functions arguments
                std::apply([&](const ExtraArgs&... extra_args) {
                    (m_instance->*m_function)(args..., extra_args...);
                    }, m_extra_args);
            }

        private:
            T* m_instance;
            void (T::* m_function)(Args... args, ExtraArgs...);
            std::tuple<ExtraArgs...> m_extra_args;
        };

        m_callback = std::make_unique<MethodWrapper>(instance, function, extra_args...);
    }
    virtual void Trigger(Args... args) override
    { 
        m_callback->Call(args...);
    } 
    
    virtual bool operator == (IEventCallback<Args...>* other) override
    {
        EventCallback<T, Args...>* otherEventCallback = dynamic_cast<EventCallback<T, Args...>*>(other);

        return otherEventCallback->m_callback == m_callback;

    }


private:    

    std::unique_ptr<ICallback<Args...>> m_callback;

};

#endif



Tips : Typically an C++ callback mechanism would return a RAII object that will do the unregistration for you when it goes out of scope.  Then you can use std::function<void (const Args&...)> and (register) lambdas to do the heavy lifting. Then there is no need to even work with runtime polymorphic callback functions .

Why do you need operator== in IEventCallback? The code shown never calls it. If for some reason you do need it, how should it work with this "extended" EventCallback? If there are two EventCallback instances that were constructed with the same object and the same member function, but different extra arguments, should they compare equal? Could those extra arguments be of a type that itself doesn't have operator==, so you can't even tell whether they are "same" or "different"?

One ready to use solution is boost.signals2. But if you need to do your own homework, start with std::function combined with std::bind_front, std::bind_back and lambda expressions. Pointer manipulation belongs to dark ages; learn proper idioms that ensure safety.

Something along these lines perhaps (not tested):
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class EventCallback : public IEventCallback<Args...>
{    
public:
    template <typename... ExtraArgs
    EventCallback(T* instance, void (T::* function)(Args..., ExtraArgs...),
                  const ExtraArgs&... extra_args) {
      m_callback = [=](Args... args) {
          (intance->*function)(args..., extra_args...);
       };
    }

    virtual void Trigger(Args... args) override
    { 
        if(m_callback)
            m_callback(args...);
    } 

private:
    std::function<void(Args...)> m_callback;
};


For that matter, you could have EventCallback constructor take an arbitrary callable. Or skip the middleman entirely, and have Event::AddListener take an arbitrary callable.

Thank you for your reply, it works well, but I'd like to know if there's a way not to use std::function, I'd like to use only pointers to member functions if possible.

You need type erasure in some form. It's baked into std::function; if you don't want to use that, you'd have to roll your own.

And how to make my own type erasure ?

The usual approach goes like this. You define a class, say, ICallback, with a pure virtual function, say Call(Args...). Inside EventCallback templated constructor, you define a local class derived from ICallback. That class would store instance, function and extra_args, and implement Call in an obvious way. The constructor would create an instance of that class and store it in a member, say std::unique_ptr<ICallback> m_callback. The technique is called "type erasure" because the type of m_callback doesn't depend on ExtraArgs

In fact, I can't figure out how I can store both the class instance and the extra arg in the same class?

Class instance as T*. Extra args as std::tuple<ExtraArgs...>

And the function ? because the function is expressed in terms of Args and the supplementary arguments are expressed in terms of ExtraArgs.
std::tuple<ExtraArgs...>
void (T::*m_function)(Args...);

I don't quite grasp the nature of the difficulty. EventCallback constructor accepts void (T::*)(Args..., ExtraArgs...) pointer - store exactly that pointer in the class.

You said I had to store the function, instance and additional arguments in a class inherited from ICallback.
And that's where I get stuck, I can't store the function and the extra arguments together, or else I haven't understood what you're advising me to do.
That is my code:
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class MyClass: public ICallback<Args...>
{
public:
virtual void Call(Args... args) override
{
}
private :
void (T::m_function)(Args...);
std::tuple<ExtraArgs...>
T m_instance;
}

I advise you to have a class with three data members: T* instance, void (T::*m_function)(Args..., ExtraArgs...) and std::tuple<ExtraArgs> extra_args_ . Just the exact copies of what's passed to EventCallback constructor. What again seems to be the problem?

yep, I thought about it but I can't declare my class with the two variadic arguments.
template<typename T, typename... Args, typename... ExtraArgs>
class MyClass : public ICallback<Args...>
{
T* instance;
void (T::* m_function)(Args..., ExtraArgs...);
std::tuple extra_args_;
}
I have this error :
C++ model parameter package missing at end of parameter list

If the class is local inside the constructor, it doesn't need to be a template at all. Args and ExtraArgs are known from enclosing template.

Consider: template <typename T> void f(T x) { struct S {T y;}; S s{x}; }; The local class inside the function template is not itself a template, but has a member of type that is the template parameter of the function.

Okay, thank you for your answers

Use broadcaster, and make your callbacks be arbitrary callables.
Use a RAII return value from registration to unregister.
using token=std::shared_ptr<void>;
template<class...Ts>
struct broadcaster{
  using listener=std::function<void(Ts...)>;
  token listen(listener l){
    auto pl=std::make_shared<listener>(std::move(l));
    ls.push_back(pl);
    return pl;
  }
  int send(Ts... ts){
    int count = 0;
    ls.erase(
      std::remove_if(ls.begin(),ls.end(),[](auto wp){return wp.expired();}),
      ls.end()
    );
    auto tmp=ls;
    for(auto l:ls) {
      if(auto pl=l.lock()) {
        ++count;
        (*pl)(ts...);
      }
    }
    return count;
  }


private:
  std::vector<std::weak_ptr<listener>> ls;
};

that should do it.  Live example.
It only cleans the list of orphan weaknptrs when someone does a .send, and could use a bit of polish, but it is insanely shorter than your version and supports partial binding easily.

@Tas A few other typoes, like .valid(), failing to actually count, and a closing } was also missing.
